# Move to Local Trash when deleting IMAP messages in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, imap, local, trash

I have tried to find a solution for this for a while now without luck. Wanted to check if there already is an add-on or easy hack before I attempt to write my own.

In my opinion this must be quite a common scenario:

1. Thunderbird is configured using IMAP.
2. In order to save mailbox storage space I want deleted messages to end up in my Local Trash folder and not in my IMAP Trash folder when messages are deleted.

Is there any way to achieve this? (I know I can move messages from IMAP Trash to Local Trash manually).

Server Settings only show IMAP folders as alternatives:

[image: Thunderbird - Server Settings]

Comment: Look for bug 182274 in bugzilla, you may find information for helping you with your attempt to write addon / hack, if you haven't done it yet since January.
I assume you know that people have been asking for this feature since 2003 and that nothing has been done yet. (Look for bug 221946 in bugzilla)

Comment: Related: [Thunderbird, IMAP, Delete a message and move it to local Trash](http://superuser.com/questions/561480/thunderbird-imap-delete-a-message-and-move-it-to-local-trash)